# Is there a way to authenticate as a service account impersonating another service account to BigQuery Node.js client?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to auth from SA_A as SA_B. (I have all the permissions and APIs set up so that's not the issue).

I've looked at the code a bit and can't figure out how to do it.

BigQuery extends Service and uses it to handle the authentication

#### Option A

```
    import { BigQuery, Dataset } from '@google-cloud/bigquery';
    import { GoogleAuth } from 'google-auth-library';

    const googleAuth = new GoogleAuth({
      scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery'],
      keyFile: 'key.json',
      clientOptions: {
        targetPrincipal: 'SA_B',
      },
    });

    const client = new BigQuery({authClient: googleAuth})
```

Won't work because even though the 'service' class which is responsible for authenticating accesses it, BigQuery's constructor does not expose it.

#### Option B

```
const client = new BigQuery({
    keyFilename: 'key.json',
    clientOptions: {
        targetPrincipal: 'SA_B',
    },
});
```

Won't work because 'service' class ignores them.